# Responsive Lightbox & Gallery issue

Tags: wordpress, plugins, gallery, wordpress-shortcode, lightbox2

I am using the wordpress plugin Responsive Lightbox & Gallery and noticed that about a week ago all my galleries have disapeared. Each post has added rlevant shortcode, but the galley created with mentioned plugin isn't visible.
Example: https://3mwkuchni.pl/sniadania/pieczony-pasztet-do-smarowania/
Has anybody any idea what could had happened?

I have switched single gallery settings - private/public, without effetcs.

Comment: maybe it's one of your plugins, you have error from autooptimize in your console